# Confusing result between 'to_date' and 'long to date' in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table called "subscription" as below.

```
desc subscription;

Name                  Null     Type       
--------------------- -------- ----------
SUBSCRIPTION_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
EXPIRATIONDATE                 DATE`
```

And output of the query as below.

```
SELECT
  subscription_id,
  expirationdate
FROM subscription
WHERE subscription_id = 41919;

SUBSCRIPTION_ID        EXPIRATIONDATE          
---------------------- -------------------------
41919                  18-JAN-14 13:45:56
```

And I'm trying to execute following query in different ways.

*1st Query returns one row:*

```
SELECT s.subscription_id
  FROM subscription$active s
 WHERE s.expirationdate - (116 / 24)
       BETWEEN TO_DATE('13-JAN-14 11:38:22', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
           AND TO_DATE('13-JAN-14 18:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   AND s.subscription_id = 41919;

SUBSCRIPTION_ID        
----------------------
41919
```

*2nd Query returns no rows:*

```
SELECT s.subscription_id
  FROM subscription$active s
 WHERE s.expirationdate - (116 / 24)
       BETWEEN (trunc(1389613102220 / (1000), 0) / (24 * 60 * 60))
                + to_date('01/01/1970', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
           AND (trunc(1389637800000 / (1000), 0) / (24 * 60 * 60))
                + to_date('01/01/1970', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
   AND s.subscription_id = 41919;

SUBSCRIPTION_ID
----------------
```

Here both the above where clause are same. 1st one is trying to use "to_date" and 2nd one converts "long to date". But when I see the out put, the first one returns a row and 2nd doesnot return any result.
I couldn't find out what is difference the 'long to date' conversion makes here.

The conversion between long to date is also correct. 
`select (trunc(1389613102220 / (1000), 0) / (24 * 60 * 60)) + to_date('01/01/1970','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual`

Output: 
`13-JAN-14 11:38:22`

And

`select (trunc(1389637800000 / (1000), 0) / (24 * 60 * 60)) + to_date('01/01/1970','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual`

Output: 
`13-JAN-14 18:30:00`

Can someone help me to understand the difference between the 1st and 2nd query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't really your epoch-based query, it's the data in your table (and to some extent the way you're constructing your dates for the non-epoch version). You are using 2-digit years and a 4-digit format mask. When you use `to_date` in your filter you're actually using the year `0014`, not `2014`; you can see that just by converting the string value, but showing the result with the full four-digit year:

```
select to_char(to_date('13-JAN-14 11:38:22', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as test_date
from dual;

TEST_DATE         
-------------------
0014-01-13 11:38:22
```

The critical part is that you're converting `14` using format model `YYYY`. As [the documentation mentions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216):

> Numeric elements are padded with leading zeros to the width of the
>   maximum value allowed for the element. For example, the `YYYY` element
>   is padded to four digits (the length of '9999')

Although that's mostly talking about `to_char` in that section, the same applies to `to_date`. When you do `to_date('14', 'YYYY')` it's interpreted as `to_date('0014', 'YYYY')`. You could use `RRRR` instead, or `RR` since you're only providing two digits of the year anyway, either of which would give you `2014`; but it's better to be explicit.

It looks like you did that during insertion as well, because your first query will only find record `41919` if it's expiration date is also in `0014`.

When you use the epoch timestamp conversion you are actually getting `2014`, so your record is really not in that range.

To confirm that, specify a format model with the full year in your initial query:

```
select subscription_id,
  to_char(expirationdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as expirationdate
from subscription
where subscription_id = 41919; 

SUBSCRIPTION_ID EXPIRATIONDATE    
--------------- -------------------
          41919 0014-01-18 13:45:56
```

You'll also see no data if you change the date string, or the format model (which only works now because Oracle is sometimes too helpful parsing these), in your first query:

```
select s.subscription_id from subscription s
where s.expirationdate - (116/24) between TO_DATE('13-JAN-14 11:38:22',
    'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss')
  and TO_DATE('13-JAN-14 18:30:00', 'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss')
and s.subscription_id=41919;
```

... which will return no rows if the table date is `0014`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The problem is because of the 2 digit year which I inserted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the full output of the explain plan, generated by querying DBMS_Xplan(), and it will show you the values being used internally as a result of evaluating those constants. That might show the presence of an unexpected data type conversion.